# Mostrar todos los input checkbox marcados pero con un salto de linea jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo esto

```
<input><?php echo $elementos?><input>
...


function updateTextArea() {  

   var allVals = [];

   $('input:checked').each(function() {

      allVals.push($(this).attr("id"));

   });

 $('div#choose').html(allVals+"<br/>")

};
$(function() { 

    $('input').click(updateTextArea);

    updateTextArea();

});
```

Buen día. Tengo este código que lo recicle de esta página. 
Funciona perfectamente pero no sale con salto de línea en mi (`div#choose`) y no sé como colocarlo para que salga cada elemento con su salto de línea de ese array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que con tu código añades un único salto de línea (`<br/>`) al final de los datos a mostrar. Deberías incluir un salto de línea por cada elemento.

La forma más sencilla es utilizar el método `join` del objeto `Array` que te permite convertir un array en una cadena indicando un separador a introducir entre cada elemento (en este caso sería el salto de línea):

```js
 $(function(){
  var allVals = ['elemento1', 'elemento2', 'elemento3'];
  $('div#choose').html(allVals.join('<br/>'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choose"></div>
```